# Connect to Homestead with mobile device

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I'm running Laravel Homestead  on my Windows PC. I want to be able to connect to my local environment with a physical phone (Android or iPhone). I've done some research but nothing seems to be working.

I've added a public network to my Homestead.yaml like the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead#network-interfaces) says to do:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox
ssl: true

#authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

#keys:
#    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\john\Documents\Github\project
      to: /home/vagrant/project
    - map: C:\Users\john\Documents\Github\project\phpmyadmin
      to: /home/vagrant/project/phpmyadmin

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/project/public
    - map: phpmyadmin.test
      to: /home/vagrant/project/phpmyadmin/public

networks:
    - type: "public_network"
      ip: "192.168.10.20"

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: false
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

If I go to 192.168.10.20 on my computer's browser, it works fine, but it's not connecting on my mobile phone and I don't know why.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

### **Look at the ports ouput when running `vagrant up`**

Before trying to add `networks` into `Homestead.yaml`, the answer might be simpler than you think. Try this:

When you run `vagrant up`, look at the initialization output.

Look for clues that perhaps you should use a different port when attempting to access the site on a local mobile device.

Like...

```
==> homestead: Fixed port collision for 80 => 8000. Now on port 2200.
```

... and/or...

```
==> homestead: Forwarding ports...
    homestead: 80 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
```

Then to access the Laravel project on a local mobile device (ie same WIFI network), try:

```
http://yourPCipAddress:2200

e.g. http://192.168.0.109:2200
```

The above works for me; I'm able to load my Laravel site on my local mobile devices.

I didn't need to make any change to Homestead or my OS hosts file.  I don't think I have any other special config elsewhere. This is a fresh install of everything on a new Ubuntu machine.

For reference, here's my Homestead.yaml and hosts files. FYI, my Homestead.yaml has an alias domain defined (mysite.local), but this domain only works on my PC because it's only defined in the PC hosts file.

**Homestead.yaml:**

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects/mywebsite/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: mywebsite.local
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

**My hosts file:**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.10.10 mywebsite.local
```

Comment: Keep in mind any firewalls on your OS; are ports being blocked? This was my case on a recent Ubuntu build after implementing the above.